# marquee animation with translate in android?

Tags: android-animation, textview, translate-animation, android

I want to create a marquee textview like following gif image, but failed
 Gif image link:-  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8gGmAFZFdG3S0tYOUJuc0d3QVU/view?usp=sharing

I had tried to do this following url
  https://github.com/ened/Android-MarqueeView
but again i failed.

AnyHelp would be greatly appreciated